# how to retrieve JSON data as checkbox and to check those values which are true in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Using AJAX I have retrieved data from API  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos (JSON data) as checkbox.For those values which are true the checkbox should be checked.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a table from an array of objects? Or how to check a checkbox input depending on a boolean value? Two completely separate issues, both with existing answers. Also, if you have successfully retrieved API data using AJAX, please don't put "how to retrieve JSON data" in the question title. You are not asking about that. You already have the array.

Answer (score -1):

You can map and join:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data
  .map(item => `<div class="task">
    <span class="userid">${item.userId}</span> <span class="id">${item.id}</span>
    <h3>${item.title}</h3>
    <label>Completed: <input type="checkbox" class="completed"${item.completed?" checked":""} /></label>
    </div>`)
  .join("")
);
```

```css
.task { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```